# How to execute the query of procedure with parameter calling in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, procedure

I am trying to execute the following code in laravel...

```
$sql = "SET @p0='$p_id'; CALL `rating_avg`(@p0);";
$pp = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
if($pp == false)die("QUERY DIDN'T EXECUTE");
```

But always showing QUERY DIDN'T EXECUTE

I am doing a web project using Laravel. My project name is Research paper management system. Our course teacher forbid us to use laravel model and told us to execute any query in the following way.
 $sql = "SOME QUERY"; mysqli($database_connect , $sql);

That's why I am trying to do the following as our teacher's terms and conditions...

```
$sql = "SET @p0='$p_id'; CALL `rating_avg`(@p0);";
$pp = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
if($pp == false)die("QUERY DIDN'T EXECUTE");
```

Here 'rating_avg' is a procedure. I have created it manually in the phpMyadmin database. While creating I found the following query...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `rating_avg`(IN `pid` INT) DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER select avg(reviewer_given_rating) AS v from paper_has_reviews where paper_id=pid;
```

Everything is okay. I just don't know how to run the query 
$sql = "SET @p0='$p_id'; CALL `rating_avg`(@p0);";

mysqli_query() isn't working here.

Comment: I love how your teacher forces you to write code that is wide open to SQL injection. Oh wait, no I don't. In the meantime, you might want to follow some tutorials as your query probably executes but doesn't return the result in the way you expect it. Start here for example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysqli/mysqli_select_query.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `DB::statement()` for this:

```php
// Splitting it into separate statements makes for better code structure.
DB::statement("SET @p0='$p_id'");
DB::statement("CALL rating_avg(@p0)");
```

But it requires that you have configured your database connection properly inside your Laravel app. I suggest you visit [official documentation on the matter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database).

Comment: I already said that my course teacher forbid to use model. I have just tried what you have suggested me to do. But here is saying DB is not found

Comment: @KaziZiaulHassan `DB` is not a model, don't confuse yourself. You tagged your question as `Laravel`, that means your question suggests using Laravel and it's tools. In Laravel all database related stuff is done through functions this `DB` facade provides you. Make sure you go through instructions in the link I've provided if you want to use Laravel. To fix your error you need to add `use DB;` or `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` in the beginning of your PHP file (look at the examples in official documentation).

Comment: If your question has nothing to do with Laravel and you don't want to use it's tools at all and you need a solution in native PHP then remove `laravel` tag from it.

Comment: Thanks :D . It works now . Thanks again for your collaboration.

Comment: How can I collect the value generated from the query "select avg(reviewer_given_rating) AS v from paper_has_reviews where paper_id=pid;" inside the procedure to web page. I want to show the generated value comes from avg(reviewer_given_rating)  in web page.

Comment: @KaziZiaulHassan use `DB::select()` instead of `DB::statement()` - it will return result of your query as array of objects.

Comment: I did "$data = DB::select("CALL rating_avg(@pid)");" as you suggest and it successfully executed also. But how can I get that avg(rivewer_given_rating) value from the array of object $data. Would you please elaborate @d3jn ?

Comment: @KaziZiaulHassan write `dump($data);` and see how it's presented - it will print the contents of `$data` variable.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56678779/how-to-parse-data-from-array-of-object
@d3jn