# How to parse data from array of object

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

I have an array of object `$data` in my code. I want to collect some of the object attribute to print in my web page. That's why I printed `dump($data)`
so that I can see the pattern how the object and their attributes distributed in the array of object `$data`.

But I could not parse anything from that after seeing `$data` through the `dump()` function.

After using `dump($data)` I found something like...

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#238 ▼
    +"data_": 8
  }
]
```

I need `"data_": 8` so that I can collect `8` from here. Why there is `#238` ?
What's the significance of it ?

Comment: Why not just do `echo $data[0]->data_`? I believe the 238 is inner object ID

Comment: No error but there is not showing 8. @dWinder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 238 should be the object id.

Try the following code:

```
foreach($data as $obj)
{
    echo $obj->data_;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do u ever try using dd method

dd($dump);

[laravel helpers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-dd)